# Java KeyListener, trying to get a Color to change according to the key pressed

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener

This is my **first** time asking on stackoverflow, so please tell me if I am doing something wrong.

I am writing a program that implements a key listener, and I am trying to get it to change a color according to which key is pressed. (see code below) However, it does not change the color, but it still registers the key pressing. 
The way I am trying to test this is with the 'b' key, as seen in the code.
Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Spring extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    private char f = 'a';
    private int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    private Color flower = new Color(a,b,c);

    public Spring() {  //Constructor
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void addNotify() { //the focus
        super.addNotify();
        requestFocus();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); //clear before next press
        g.drawString("the key that pressed is " + f, 0, 10);
        g.setColor(flower);
        Polygon flowa = new Polygon();
        flowa.addPoint(220,270);
        flowa.addPoint(250,300);
        flowa.addPoint(270,270);
        flowa.addPoint(250,300);
        g.fillPolygon(flowa);
        g.fillRect(250,300,30,30);

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { //when key is typed, do something
        f = e.getKeyChar(); //modify value of f
        switch (f){
        case 'a': 
            a = 10;
            b = 10;
            c = 10;
        case 'b': 
            a = 223;
            b = 45;
            c = 45;
            System.out.println("Bals");
        case 'c': 
            a = 10;
            b = 10;
            c = 10;
        case 'd': 
            a = 10;
            b = 10;
            c = 10;
        case 'e': 
            a = 10;
            b = 10;
            c = 10;
        case 'f': 
            a = 10;
            b = 10;
            c = 10;
        case 'g': 
            a = 10;
            b = 10;
            c = 10;
        case 'h': 
            a = 10;
            b = 10;
            c = 10;
        case 'i': 
            a = 10;
            b = 10;
            c = 10;
        case 'j': 
            a = 10;
            b = 10;
            c = 10;
        case 'k': 
            a = 10;
            b = 10;
            c = 10;
        case 'l': 
            a = 10;
            b = 10;
            c = 10;
        case 'm': 
            a = 10;
            b = 10;
            c = 10;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] s) { //main method, creates the frame
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().add(new Spring());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're calling `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting, then you wan't need `g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());`

Comment: I think `repaint()` is the preferred method.

Comment: @saiarcot895 The OP is calling `repaint` at the bottom of there `keyTyped` method

Comment: Nitpick: `paintComponent` doesn't need to be `public`, it should be `protected`, there is no reason for anybody to ever be able to call `paintComponent`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: ah, my bad. I initially didn't see what you meant.

Comment: @saiarcot895 Not the most clear comment in the world :P - ps +1 to your answer though ;)

Comment: Errr `break` your switch case statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just setting the variables `a`, `b`, and `c`. Changing these variables won't change the numbers used by `flower`, because `flower` is using the numbers you passed in, not the variables you are using.

You need to create a new `Color` object in each instance, something like this:

```
flower = new Color(20, 230, 210);
```

Also, don't forget to add in `break;` lines between cases; otherwise, your `flower` object will be the color that you last listed.

Also, you might want to use an implementation of the [KeyAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html) class, which allows you to define only the methods you want to use instead of all the methods, instead of having your own class `KeyListener`.

Comment: +1. Also worth noting that the OP should be using `break` after their case statements.

Comment: Ah, yes. I'll add that along with another suggestion.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was surprised at how fast you answered!

Answer (score 1):

*saiarcot895 answer is correct in that it solves the problem at hand (+1).  This is an example of how it might be achieved using a the [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API*

`KeyListener` is generally a poor choice for monitoring key events as it suffers from focus related issues, which you are attempting to resolve, but are not gurenteed to work.

A better solution is to use the [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API, which provides you with the ability to configure the focus level at which key events are triggered.

The problem you will have is the fact that you have a large number of possible key strokes to use.  To this end, I simply used a `Map` to map the key code to an `Action` which was used to set the desired color

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Spring extends JPanel {

    private Color flower = Color.BLACK;
    private String key;

    public Spring() {
        Map<Integer, ColorAction> mapColors = new HashMap<>(25);
        mapColors.put(KeyEvent.VK_F, new ColorAction(this, "F", new Color(10, 10, 10)));
        mapColors.put(KeyEvent.VK_B, new ColorAction(this, "B", new Color(223, 45, 45)));

        InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap am = getActionMap();

        for (Integer keyCode : mapColors.keySet()) {

            KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0);
            im.put(ks, ks);
            am.put(ks, mapColors.get(keyCode));

        }
    }

    public void update(String ks, Color color) {
        flower = color;
        key = ks;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 500);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("the key that pressed is " + key, 0, 10);
        g.setColor(flower);
        Polygon flowa = new Polygon();
        flowa.addPoint(220, 270);
        flowa.addPoint(250, 300);
        flowa.addPoint(270, 270);
        flowa.addPoint(250, 300);
        g.fillPolygon(flowa);
        g.fillRect(250, 300, 30, 30);

    }

    public static void main(String[] s) { //main method, creates the frame
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.getContentPane().add(new Spring());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ColorAction extends AbstractAction {

        private Spring spring;
        private String key;
        private Color color;

        private ColorAction(Spring spring, String ks, Color color) {
            this.spring = spring;
            this.key = ks;
            this.color = color;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            spring.update(key, color);
        }

    }
}
```

If you find it useful, an up-vote would be welcome, but saiarcot895 answer should remain marked as correct